# Add Custom Method to JPARepository with Generics

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Assume I have a Entity called `Product`. I design a Repo as

```
@Repository
interface ProductRepository implements JPARepository<Product, Integer>{}
```

This would inherit all the default methods such as `save, findAll` etc;

Now I want to have one custom method, which is also a common method for other entities. I added another interface and implementation

```
interface CustomRepository<T,ID>{ public void customMethod() }
class CustomRepositoryImpl implements CustomRepository<T,ID>{ public void customMethod(){} }
```

And I rewrite the ProductRepository as

```
@Repository
interface ProductRepository implements 
JPARepository<Product, Integer>,
CustomRepository<Product, Integer>
{}
```

Now, this does not give me any compilation error. But during runtime, I get this error:

> No property 'customMethod' is found for Product

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be trying to add custom behaviour to a single repository, namely `ProductRepository`. However, the code is structured as if custom behaviour needs to be added to all repositories (`CustomRepository` is not specific to `Product`s). Hence, the error.

---

> **Step 1**: Declare a custom repository

```
interface CustomRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> {
  void customMethod();
}
```

> **Step 2**: Add custom behaviour to the required repository

```
interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Integer>
                                    , CustomRepository<Product, Integer> {}
```

> **Step 3**: Add a `Product` specific implementation

```
class ProductRepositoryImpl implements CustomRepository<Product, Integer> { ... }
```

*Note*: The class must be named `ProductRepositoryImpl` for Spring Data JPA plumbing to pick it up automatically.

---

A working example is available [on Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/42337222).

---

If you would rather add custom behaviour to all repositories, refer to the [relevant section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories) in the official documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the code link. What is the class 'Model' for. What is the definition of the class. Also ,ProductrepositoryImpl should implement ProductRepository else, spring will not create an instance

Comment: All the code is included in the sample. Run integration tests as `mvn test`.

Comment: Ok. Model @MappedSuperClass is new here. But again. I could see the customMethod is getting implemented in ProductRepositoryImpl. This would make it available only to Product. If I have new Entity called Service. I would again have to write the same code "Ditto". How do I move the implementation to generic class

Comment: the reason why am trying to move it to common class is that, that implementation is exactly same for almost 10 entities. It would be bad to repeat the same set of code in each and every repo file

Comment: Basic inheritance - `abstract class CustomRepositoryImpl<T, ID> implements CustomRepository<T, ID> { public void customMethod() { ... } }`, `class ProductRepositoryImpl extends CustomRepositoryImpl<Product, Long>`.

Comment: Yes. That normal inheritance. Your code works absolutely fine. but when I try the same in my SpringBootApplication am getting
"This class [class com.tcs.datahub.resident.entity.Model] does not define an IdClass" error.

Comment: That's a different error. Post it as a separate question with supporting code.

Comment: As a general OOPS it works. The problem is only when I go with spring-data-jpa. Thats why I tagged with it.

Comment: Got it working. Marking this as answer but you have to done more change.. which I will add as answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This is for people who are trying to get this work in a SpringBoot application

follow whatever posted by @manish.   Working code here [Working Code](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/42337222)

You just have to make one small change. 
Define Model class as

```
@MappedSuperclass
@IdClass(ModelID.class)
public abstract class Model implements Serializable
```

define the ID class as

```
public class ModelID implements Serializable{

    @Column(name = "id")
    @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id

    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



}
```

This got me working!